# Can I build a localhost resided on an IOS(ipad ,iphone) or Android tablets with Node.js(JXcore) ?

Tags: ios, node.js, ipad, localhost, jxcore

Background: we have an existing web application written in JAVA with tomcat, JVM environment etc.

And now, the client want to have the partial application running on their tablet devices in an **offline environment** which breaks the rule of Client-Server (no internet access !)

In order to do less coding/development, our team decided to use nodejs and to write a light weight **platform independent server side code**, (localhost +browser access, it seems awkward, but it is impossible to rewrite the whole application in Swift and SDK etc).

Can this be achieved though JXcore or other frameworks?
(it is just a CRUD type application)

Or what other solution you can think of in this situation. (no internet connection environment)

Answer (score 0):

**No**. You can't create a native iOS app using Node.js

And also there isn't any bridging between Swift and Node.js

Though there is something called [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) which exposes the Objective-C runtime to Node.js in a high-level.

Comment: I thought JXcore is a built in app for hosting nodejs on ios device, in this case , I can access the service via "localhost:8080" on browser ,something like that.